# Extracting a Point from MuItipoint and use it for a ST_DWithin query

Tags: postgis, srid, multipoint, st-dwithin

I have a MultiPoint geometry column which has only one point (DB is a live server which cannot be changed now).

I need to find all points within a certain distance from a fixed point I provide to the query.

I tried to extract a point from the MultiPoint and use that as data for the `ST_DWithin` query but I still get a `"Operation on mixed SRID geometries"` error.

My query is as below:

```
SELECT o.id, ST_AsText(o.geom)
FROM table AS o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, ST_GeometryN(geom, 1) AS pt
    FROM table
) AS p
ON o.id = p.id 
WHERE ST_DWithin(p.pt, ST_MakePoint(-112.779861,52.193760)::geography, 1000);
```

Comment: And what do you get: ST_DWithin((p.pt)::geography, ST_MakePoint(-112.779861,52.193760)::geography, 1000).

Comment: Tried this as well. Same Error.

Comment: In what SRID do you have the original geometry? You need to lead either to the type of geography or to the type of geometry...

Comment: And don't forget to accept your answer, as he's solved your question...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and was nothing but setting the SRID to the geometry. Since, setting the SRID does not change the geometry itself, this works.

```
SELECT o.id, ST_AsText(o.geom)
FROM table AS o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeometryN(geom, 1), 4326) AS pt
    FROM table
) AS p
ON o.id = p.id 
WHERE ST_DWithin(p.pt::geography, ST_MakePoint(-112.779861,52.193760)::geography, 1000);
```

Comment: `ST_Dwithin` happily accepts a *Multi* geometry; if there's only a single *Point* in your *MultiPoint*, the results will be the same, plus it can use the spatial index on the column!

Comment: Indeed, all features should have the correct SRID encoded in the geometry itself, not applied during extract.